# How to solve sum with sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

I have this equation system that I need to solve

[image]

I know the following variables: `Sale Price`, `n`, `BR`, and a different value for each `t_i`. Furthermore, I know that all values of `p_i` are equal.

I would like to solve this for `p_i`. How can I do that?

In the next part, I would like to set `p_i` based on the result above, and change the `Sale Price` variable and observe how `BR` changes with respect to that.

Is this possible to do with Sympy?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need SymPy. Since all the `Pi` are equal, they can be factored out of the summation. Therefore,

```
P_i = P = (Sale Price) * sum_i^n { (BR/12 + 1)^{12t_i} }
```

---

For the second part, in general there is no a closed-formed solution for `BR`, since in the simplest case `BR` is a polynomial function of the `Sales Price`, and even polynomial equations only have [closed-form solutions for equations up to degree 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem).

Comment: thanks, I've realised this. what about part 2, solving for `BR`?

Answer (score 0):

Sales Price = S

S = Sum(P<sub>i</sub>/((BR/12)+1)<sup>12t<sub>i</sub></sup>))

If P<sub>i</sub>-s are equal  then you can treat it as constant.

P<sub>i</sub> = S x Sum(12/BR+12)<sup>12<sub>i</sub></sup>

P<sub>i</sub> = S x Y

```
t = [t1, t2, ... ,tn]
Y=0
for i in range(1,n+1):
   Y+=(12/(BR+12))**(12*t[i])
```

Now you should give us details about t and BR, to produce normal code and get results :)

Comment: He asked about solving it using `sympy`.